# How do I perform a ActiveRecord search and remove everyone up to a specific record from an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I just tried performing a method, and it failed after hitting a specific object.

Knowing the email attribute of that object, how can I create an array, and limit the return to only those objects that are after that specific object?

**This is a Rails 2 project**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say:

```
your_array.take_while {|elt| elt.email != email }
```

Or for 1.9.2:

```
your_array.slice_before{|elt| elt.email == email }.first
```

Comment: Hmm..is this a rails 3 method? I should note I'm using Rails 2

Comment: `.take_while` works perfect! Geez, you're a true ruby genius for knowing that little gem.

Comment: it's really great to have a look at all Enum module treasures :)

Answer (score 0):

if you have an array try something like

```
irb(main):030:0> ary = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
irb(main):031:0> ary.values_at( ary.index(4)..-1 )
=> [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help, as where will return all records after the id == id

```
id = SomeModel.where( :email => 'email_you@kn.ow' ).first.id

SomeModel.where( "id > ?", id )
```

Comment: So jealous of Rails 3 right now, bt this is a Rails 2 question. Thanks for the answer though!